# Entity Framework and Linq equivalent in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new to Android. I literally just learn Android few days ago. I am just wondering, is there Entity Framework and LINQ equivalent for Android?

Also, I need to store/cache record to a local database. What the best database to use? I am thinking of using SQLite. Is it appropriate for Android?

Thanks!

Comment: No problem . You can use `SQLite`

Answer (score 1):

You need an ORM(Object-Relational Mapper), there is a good cross platform ORM called [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) , Realm gives you a much more programmatic way of accessing  and storing data in Objects just like LinQ or EntityFramework and executes queries pragmatically in an object oriented manner.

Sample Realm Code

```
RealmResults<User> result = realm.where(User.class)
                                 .greaterThan("age", 10)  // implicit AND
                                 .beginGroup()
                                      .equalTo("name", "Peter")
                                      .or()
                                      .contains("name", "Jo")
                                 .endGroup()
                                 .findAll();
```

[Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for that. It seems what I need. But Realms doesn't support compound key :(  which is a pain. Do you know if they will support compound key anytime soon?

Answer (score 0):

SqLite is appropriate to store local Data for example: if you are retrieving  JSON, u can us an sqlite database to store some data for the offline mode, and of course u can use the cache as well, but i recommend u SQLite.

Hope i helped.